# How to automatically show error when user input is invalid without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

When the user clicks on an input field and starts typing, I want the box to be red and show an error message about why the content is invalid until the input content is valid. I want to do this without reloading the page, which is what my code does right now:

```
if amount and price and first_name and last_name and email and (have_error == False):
```

do some stuff

```
else:
```

show error message

html:

```
        <label class = "sell_label">amount</label>
        <input type="text" class = "sell_input" name="amount" value="{{amount}}">
        {{error_amount}}


        <label class = "sell_label">price</label>
        <input type="text" class = "sell_input" name="price" value="{{price}}">
        {{error_price}}


        <label class = "sell_label">first name</label>
        <input type="text" class = "sell_input" name="first_name" value="{{first_name}}">


        <label class = "sell_label">last name</label>
        <input type="text" class = "sell_input" name="last_name" value="{{last_name}}">


        <label class = "sell_label">email</label>
        <input type="text" class = "sell_input" name="email" value="{{email}}">
        {{error_email}}

        <input type="submit" class = "sell_button" value = "okay">  
    <div class="error">{{error}}</div>
```

How would I incorporate Javascript into my html to detect when the input content is valid?